# Destructor called before move-constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, move-semantics

I have a function which looks something like this, it returns a noncopyable class by movesemantics:

```
MyClass&& MyFunction() {
  MyClass myClass;
  do some stuff;
  return std::move(myClass);
}
```

And then it's accessed by

```
main() {
  MyClass myClass = MyFunction();
}
```

The class utilizes `boost::noncopyable` for copyprevention. It has constructor, move constructor and move assignment.
My problem is, the destructor gets called before the move constructor. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a reference to a local variable. It doesn't matter if it is an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference.

You probably should just do

```
MyClass MyFunction() {
  MyClass myClass;
  do some stuff;
  return myClass;
}
```

and let the compiler figure out how to copy or move the result.

Comment: I thought you explicitly returned rvalues.

Comment: Yes, this was expected early on. Later it was discovered that it wasn't entirely true. See [Want speed? Pass by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: The compiler will always move `myClass` in this case.

Comment: @BoPersson: In this case I wasnt looking for speed, the actuall class handles a hardware resource and cant be copied. I just want to skip returning a pointer\smart pointer.